# SQLDataAdapter is updating, but it is appending to the Database and not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server

I have an application I have been working on and up until now I have been using Access as a Database. I am switching it over to SQL and I am kinda new to it.

My code is as follows

```
public bool Update_DB_FromTable(DataTable DTable)
{
    try
    {

        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + hostname + " ;User ID=SALX; Password=password;" +
                              "database=" + dbname + "; " +
                              "connection timeout=30");
        myConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo." + tablename, myConnection);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
        SqlCommandBuilder b = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
        int count = da.Update(DTable);
        myConnection.Close();
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This works, BUT every time it runs its just appends the data to the end of the database and doesn't "Update" the database like in Access. worst part is because it creates many duplicate entries I cant manually delete them from the database..

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

-Sean-

This might be a really rookie question but i am stumped..

Comment: Can you post the code where you initially enter the data into the DataTable?  Thanks.

Comment: At first I was filling the datatable from OleDbDataAdapter.Fill (table from MS Access) and when I updated the sqlDataAdapter with that table nothing happened. so I pragmatically built a new DataTable from that DataTable and updated. which brings me to the problem of it being inserted, everytime it runs it just appends all the records to the bottom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rows in "DTable" decide what happens with the corresponding row in the database. if a row in "DTable" has status "isNew" then the row will be inserted, if the status is "modified" the db-table will be updated.

Comment: k3b is right. For DataAdapter to work as you expect, you must SELECT the record into the datatable, update it, then dataadapter will recognize the record as an update. You can't insert a record as the data table does not recognize that it is in update, unless you call DataRow.SetModified(). That might also have the same impact. But then how would you know when a row should be modified vs inserted?

Comment: hmmm so perhaps my approach to this is all wrong, Im pulling the table from an MS Access database and then need the SQL table to reflect. Basically trying to keep a local access database synchronized with a remote SQL database

Comment: Thanks k3b, makes perfect sense now!